# Custom post type categories + permalinks

Tags: wordpress, categories, permalinks

Together with my friend we've approached a weird issue. He's got a portfolio divided into few pillars: highlights/commercial/portraits etc. as a photographer often he makes a sessions which covers few of those areas. That's why on his website he can have POST1 assigned to categories: highlights/commercial/potraits..

so in each page which shows specific category same post1 might be present. And its ok. Issues are following:

when enter e.g.commercial category page this postA is visible but it's permalink might be: mydomain.com/portraits/posts1 -> why is that? I thought it should show same category as page one.

when I'm viewing post1 none of the menu is not highlighted as a current one. And its weird because if im looking on a post from portraits category, and my menu includes all categories, then one of them should be marked as current.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen that on a site that had multiple categories assigned to single posts before too. It appears that the "oldest" category will appear in the permalink, even if you visit from a different category's page. This is the category that was created first, no matter which order they're added to the post. (Removing and adding the same category has no effect on the order.)

If you have 3 categories assigned though, any one of them should still send the visitor to the same post, so it shouldn't cause issues with 404s.

I think tags are intended to be used instead of categories, when you need multiple labels on a single post, though the site I worked on used multiples of both categories and tags on each post.